# How to find the L2 cache size in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, debian

I wanted to know how to find L2 cache size in Linux...

for L1 cache size, I am doing the following

```
pico /proc/cpuinfo
```

what about L2 cache size?

Answer (score 34):

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/size`

or check `dmidecode`

or use `lshw`

Comment: How does `lshw` help here?

Answer (score 31):

**EDIT 3**: Heh, sorry, just do `sudo dmidecode -t cache` and it will show you your CPU's cache information. To tell what section you are looking at (L1 or L2), look at the `Configuration:` line. You want `Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2`.

Answer (score 21):

You should check the following [tool](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/). It gives the most accurate information from all the tools I've tried.
This is the command line version output:

```
~$ lstopo-no-graphics
Machine (7984MB)
  Socket L#0
    L2 L#0 (4096KB)
      L1d L#0 (32KB) + L1i L#0 (32KB) + Core L#0 + PU L#0 (P#0)
      L1d L#1 (32KB) + L1i L#1 (32KB) + Core L#1 + PU L#1 (P#1)
    L2 L#1 (4096KB)
      L1d L#2 (32KB) + L1i L#2 (32KB) + Core L#2 + PU L#2 (P#2)
      L1d L#3 (32KB) + L1i L#3 (32KB) + Core L#3 + PU L#3 (P#3)
```

And this is the graphical interface:[image]

Answer (score 18):

Just use: lscpu

Sample output:

```
$ lscpu 
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               3401.000
BogoMIPS:              6784.57
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Comment: `lscpu` is not accurate on some CPUs with exotic configuration. For example the CPU from [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/889627/427889) gives the following (omitted some info):
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Stepping:              11
CPU MHz:               1866.742
BogoMIPS:              3733.48
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
The CPU is [Xeon L5320](http://ark.intel.com/products/29767/Intel-Xeon-Processor-L5320-8M-Cache-1_86-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) with **8MB** L2 total.

Answer (score 10):

**`getconf`**

```
getconf -a | grep CACHE
```

gives:

```
LEVEL1_ICACHE_SIZE                 32768
LEVEL1_ICACHE_ASSOC                8
LEVEL1_ICACHE_LINESIZE             64
LEVEL1_DCACHE_SIZE                 32768
LEVEL1_DCACHE_ASSOC                8
LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE             64
LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE                  262144
LEVEL2_CACHE_ASSOC                 8
LEVEL2_CACHE_LINESIZE              64
LEVEL3_CACHE_SIZE                  20971520
LEVEL3_CACHE_ASSOC                 20
LEVEL3_CACHE_LINESIZE              64
LEVEL4_CACHE_SIZE                  0
LEVEL4_CACHE_ASSOC                 0
LEVEL4_CACHE_LINESIZE              0
```

Or for a single level:

```
getconf LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE
```

The cool thing about this interface is that it is just a wrapper around the POSIX `sysconf` C function (cache arguments are non-POSIX extensions), and so it can be used from C code as well:

```
long l2 = sysconf(_SC_LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE);
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

**x86 CPUID instruction**

The CPUID x86 instruction also offers cache information, and can be directly accessed by userland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

glibc seems to use that method for x86. I haven't confirmed by step debugging / instruction tracing, but the source for 2.28 [`sysdeps/x86/cacheinfo.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86/cacheinfo.c;h=b9444ddd52051e05183463340f4dd3cf3e61f4dc;hb=3c03baca37fdcb52c3881e653ca392bba7a99c2b#l281) does that:

```
__cpuid (2, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
```

TODO create a minimal C example, lazy now, asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283171/how-to-receive-l1-l2-l3-cache-size-using-cpuid-instruction-in-x86

ARM also has an architecture-defined mechanism to find cache sizes through registers such as the Cache Size ID Register (CCSIDR), see the [ARMv8 Programmers' Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/den0024/a/DEN0024A_v8_architecture_PG.pdf) 11.6 "Cache discovery" for an overview.

Comment: Weirdly enough `getconf` just never works on ARM! it returns 0 for all cache levels, although cache is enabled. I tested this on a beaglebone black as well as on an NVIDA Jetson TK1. Happen to know why? (Maybe related: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu* never contain any  entry wrt cache either). Only trace of cache is in dmesg, but that doesn't give you a size. It only tells you there is cache.

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn no idea, I would try to look into Linux kernel source. Let me know if you find something out.

Answer (score 4):

`dmesg | grep cache` will show your L1 and L2 related information.

Comment: Or dmesg (or dmesg.boot) and search for the CPU model. Then google on that.