# Debian Linux Server - Size of L1 and L2 cache

Tags: linux, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [finding L2 cache size in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/55776/finding-l2-cache-size-in-linux)

I am using Debian Linux Server and want to know the size of L1 and L2 cache. Can anybody help me, how to get that ?

Comment: You could just google the processor model. I think `cpuinfo` may show It

Comment: @SimonSheehan, No. I tried that one. Just gives cache size, not by L1, L2.

Comment: @Arpssss Please, check my comment on a non-accepted answer: http://superuser.com/questions/419328/debian-linux-server-size-of-l1-and-l2-cache/507432#comment1188671_507432 If you have a more exotic CPU the accepted answer could not do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dmidecode` should give you this info.

For my CPU, for instance, it shows the following output:

```
Handle 0x0002, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Through
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 64 KB
    Maximum Size: 64 KB
    Supported SRAM Types:
            Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Through
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 256 KB
    Maximum Size: 256 KB
    Supported SRAM Types:
            Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L3-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 3072 KB
    Maximum Size: 3072 KB
    Supported SRAM Types:
            Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: <OUT OF SPEC>
```

From this you can see I have an L1 cache of 64kb, an L2 cache of 256kb and an L3 cache of 3072kb.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is a duplicate of

[finding L2 cache size in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/55776/finding-l2-cache-size-in-linux)

In both cases, however, dmidecode didn't work for me, which makes sense, because it reports BIOS information, which is not always present or accurate. So, best choice for me was:

```
find /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cache/index*/size -print -exec cat {} \;
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/size
32K
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index1/size
32K
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/size
6144K
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cache/index0/size
32K
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cache/index1/size
32K
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cache/index2/size
6144K
```

Comment: I have [Xeon L5320](http://ark.intel.com/products/29767/Intel-Xeon-Processor-L5320-8M-Cache-1_86-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) and this is the only way to obtain the correct info in Linux (every other way reports 4MB L2 cache). The problem is that these processors are with 2 physical dies per chip and 2 cores are sharing half of the 8MB L2 cache. You can check the sharing by:~$ find /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cache/index*/shared_cpu_list -print -exec cat {} \;

Answer (score 2):

you can use lshw to find cache information. if not installed, you should be get it from the repo.

Answer (score 1):

x86info is a decent tool for getting processor info if you are running an i386/amd64 box.