# What are suitable values for gcc parameter l2-cache-size considering hardware L2 cache size?

Tags: memory, cpu, cache, gcc

During compilation optimization this question about best guesses for gnu `gcc` compiler parameter `--param l2-cache-size=`? (default is number for kB block size)
came up.
What are recommendable values for cpu core cluster with shared L2 cache, cpu clusters with united L2 cache on single MMU (memory management unit) and cpu cores with private L2 cache for each single core?

Getting L2 cache sizes¹ on Linux distributions can be done by console commands like:
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/size` (for cpu0 on multicore system, for example)
`find /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cache/index*/size -print -exec cat {} \;`
`lshw | grep -B 11 -C 11 -e level=2`
`dmidecode -t cache`
`lstopo-no-graphics`

Is this specific enough for requesting support at gcc mailing list or is there more widespread documentation available for L2 cache related compiler flags?

Thx

1) short summary of [How to find the L2 cache size in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/55776/how-to-find-the-l2-cache-size-in-linux)

Comment: If gcc guesses a wrong default cache size (L1I, L1D, L2ID, L3ID, L4ID) it might help knowing this `--param l2-cache-size`, btw: additional cores vs. cache sizes and cache misses  https://superuser.com/a/317785/981508

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been raised in bug-report
[Bug 87444: 'gcc -marc=native' sets L2 cache size equal to L3 cache size on i7 and i5 CPU](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87444).

It seems like the parameter `l2-cache-size` does not necessarily refer to the L2
cache. It is actually dynamically selected by `gcc` to be the same as either
the L3 cache size and is only equal to the L2 cache if there is no L3 cache.

A developer remarks that it should have really been renamed to `last-level-cache`.
So if there is an L4 cache, `gcc` will use that size.

I don't think that it is a good idea to change this parameter. But in case you do,
it is remarked that this parameter is only used for some small heuristics
and is seemed by the tone of the comment to be relatively unimportant.

Comment: Thx @harrymc: Would you suggest a cpu/gpu/npu benchmark (from source compilable tool?) setting for clearifying on individual hardware (arch, fs, software) situations? (corrected after timeout) ... lowering l2-cache-size would most probably increase cache-misses (maybe there's some comparison on that available, even if cost of compiling effort is higher than resulting binaries performance gain) ... or something to save energy instead of knowing in detail?

Comment: The best source for benchmarks is [PassMark](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/).